# Any performance gain when using ng-if-start instead of multiple ng-if?

Tags: angularjs

Let's say we have the following markup:

```
<div ng-if="isVisible"></div>
<div ng-if="isVisible"></div>
...
<div ng-if="isVisible"></div>
```

We can replace it with:

```
<div ng-if-start="isVisible"></div>
<div></div>
...
<div ng-if-end></div>
```

I prefer the second way, because it keeps the code DRY.

But I wonder, is the second way better from performance point of view? This can be not so obvious as it seems to be, because angularJS could do some kind of optimization on multiple ng-if with the same condition (that is just my suggestion, doesn't have any idea if it really does).

Any ideas? Could not find any information about it.

Comment: any reason to not wrap the whole bottom block in one ng-if?

Comment: that's just a sample, the real situation is worse :-) I deal with <td>

Comment: several `ng-if` might create multiple watchers (which will slow the app down). `ng-if` itself is not just hiding the DOM, but removing it, which takes time. I'm only guessing that reducing their number will help

Comment: thereare many optimizations you can do before the performance different becomes noticable, I think this answer really depends on the content inside etc. If you really wanted to know this answer, you can test it find out; however, ng-if inside of ng-repeat in a <td> is readable then ng-if-start and ng-if-end. You also assume your ng-ifs tds are in sequence etc etc. Don't let it bother you and just ng-if all the way by keeping it simple. If performance becomes a problem 1) remove the columns from array before render and do dynamic tr td render. Might get more performance boost there.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey that is what I thought too, but wanted to be sure :-)

Comment: @Axr yeah I think I'll have to test in the end, but I have a lot to improve and didn't want to spend the time in vain :-) thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Each `ng-if` you use creates a watcher in the background which, if you have enough of them, will affect performance.

In this specific case `ng-if-start` would be more performant as less watchers will be created and thus it is doing less work.

In this kinds of cases I tend to use `ng-switch` which is especially helpful if you need multiple `if` statements. It can reduce the number of watches over multiple if statements.